# No code coverage after Sonar upgrade to version 3.6.2

Tags: code-coverage, sonarqube

We were running a sonar server with an old version (3.4.1) with an embedded H2 database.
While migrating to an oracle databse we were upgrading our sonar server to the most recent version 3.6.2.

Upgrade finished successful (except it is not possible to keep the historical data). But after the upgrade was done sonar didn't show the code coverage any more.

Using the old sonar instance the coverage analysis still works. We did not change any sonar code coverage settings (leaving it to default: jacoco), just starting the analysis from within Jenkins via the Sonar plugin.

Did anyone had the same, a similar problem or any idea how to fix this?
Is there anything new, we have to configure?

Comment: Could you please provide the log file and your pom file?

Comment: I'll create a minimal example, as the projects pom is too large to post here.

Comment: While creating a minimal example I discovered, that cobertura was set as default code coverage tool. As the projects use Java 1.7 this is not working. After resetting this setting, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the value of **sonar.java.coveragePlugin** in sonar settings was set to cobertura, so it was just a wrong configuration.

Always keep in mind, that one can define global and project specific settings in sonar.